# Unable to reduce the size of Xamarin forms app while exporting to APK file

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I have created a simple application in Xamarin forms, with 5 Tabbed pages, each of which has a WebView in it which calls 5 different websites. Nothing more. Current size of APK is 17 MB.

I tried all the methods available on Google to reduce the size of my app. I don't understand which part I am missing.
I have enabled multi-dex,code shrinker, Linking enabled everything mentioned.

I am attaching the screenshot of my settings, APK-analyzer result and the code for my project.

Link to project solution:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18i3j6qDzlm4nN6DFHjBPLCW9Ab2WdG08?usp=sharing

[image: Warning getting while uploading to playstore]

[image: Android Options settings][image: Build options image]
[image: APK Analyzer result][image: Advanced Android Options]

Comment: 17 MB is not very big

Comment: What is your goal here? Have you tried an App Bundle in addition here to avoid the ABI tax?

Comment: 17 MB for a Xamarin-based app is small relative to the fact that you are including two native (.so) mono libraries.

Comment: i have nothing but Webview in the code, what if i write some code as well?

And while publishing the app in the playstore it is giving me lot of unused code..

Comment: Hello @JonDouglas,
I have tried using app bundle as well. But no change

Comment: @SushiHangover
I have attached a image, that i am getting an error while uploading the app to playstore

Comment: If you just want the error to go away switch to app bundle packaging aab instead of apk. Also, I would turn off multi-dex, which you probably don't need, switch dex compiler to d8, switch code shrinker to r8, and based on the archive manager that brought down the expected app size to about 15.5 mb.

Comment: @AbhijeetRaj Google's Play Store has deprecated APKs in favor of App Bundles, you that is how you are deploying your app, you must switch (note: it will not really make you app that much smaller as the mono SO's still have to included). https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-app-bundle/

Comment: @AbhijeetRaj As Jason said that your project apk 17MB is not very big, but if you still want to reduce some unused resource or code, I suggest you can take a look:[Shrinking Your Android App Size](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/shrinking-android-app-size/), there are many steps to reduce your app size, you can try.

Answer (score 1):

Select `App Bundle` instead of `APK` for `Android Package Format` in `Android Options`. Also, check `Generate one package per selected ABI` create a separate packages for armabi-v7a and one for arm64-v8a.

Edit: rereading that error message sounds like using `App Bundle` will automatically optimize for separate ABIs which i was not aware of. You might not need to check `Generate one package per selected ABI`, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: `App Bundle` & `Generate one package per selected ABI` do not benefit each other. They are for separate use-cases and generally speaking, App Bundle handles this for you dynamically for Google Play Store, but if you need individual packages for stores / ad-hoc that doesn't support App Bundle, then you'd use that.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable Application App bundles (.aab). It will reduce your application size even more once deployed through the Google Play store. (And remove this warning on the store submission)

To enable it, look in your *.Droid.csproj properties

[image: csproj options]

This [xamarin blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-app-bundle/) is a good reference.